# Automatically update categorized symbology when adding new text values

Tags: qgis, style, update, categorized-renderer

Is there a way to automatically update the categorized (or rule-based) symbology based on random colors to take into account new values?
My question is particularly true when dealing with a text variable/column to create the style...

As an example, I create a categorized symbology from a column "species name" which has 50 different species. When a new species is added to the layer, it displays as "else" or "all values" color symbol.
I would like a new color symbol to be created to display the newly added species, without manual setting.

Comment: I don't think an automated way is desirable (you don't always want to show all categories). Anyway clicking the Classify button again will add the missing categories without changing those already present…

Comment: In my case, I do want an automated way, instead of realizing later that different new species have the same symbol/color.